# Count data in a buffer TCP

Tags: c

In C, how can i count data received in a char buffer server?
For example, client sends in a single message "1 2 3" and server has to count these data and send to client "3" which is the number read of data.

This is the client:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus= 0;
    char buffsend[256];
    char buffrecv[256];
    char buff[256];
    int i, n, length;
    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;

    if (3 != argc) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <server> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    /* create a streaming socket      */
    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for connecting */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use the IP address sent as an argument for the server address  */
    //bzero(&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer));
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //inet_addr(argv[2], &simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr);
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  connect to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connect successful!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect to address!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
    }





    /* get the message from the server   */


    do {

        printf("insert num of data or terminate ('0'): ");
        fgets(buffsend,256,stdin);
        n=atoi(buffsend);
        if(n>6) {
          printf("Error\n");

         }
        else {
                length=strlen(buffsend);
                for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
                   printf("insert number: ");
                   length=strlen(buffsend);
                   buffsend[length-1]=' ';
                   fgets(buffsend+length,256-length,stdin); }

                   printf("\n");
                 write(simpleSocket, buffsend, strlen(buffsend));
             }

      } while((n!=0) && (n>0));



    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;

}
```

This the server:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus = 0;
    char buff[256];
    char message[256];
    int n, i, length, conta=0;
    int media=0;
    int varianza=0;
    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;

    if (2 != argc) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for listening */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use INADDR_ANY to bind to all local addresses  */
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  bind to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = bind(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer,sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bind completed!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind to address!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
    }

    /* lets listen on the socket for connections      */
    returnStatus = listen(simpleSocket, 5);

    if (returnStatus == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot listen on socket!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1)

    {

        struct sockaddr_in clientName = { 0 };
    int simpleChildSocket = 0;
    int clientNameLength = sizeof(clientName);

    /* wait here */

        simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);

    if (simpleChildSocket == -1) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot accept connections!\n");
        close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);

    }

        /* handle the new connection request  */
    /* write out our message to the client */

        while(read(simpleChildSocket, buff, 256)) {
             printf("Data received: %s\n", buff);
              bzero(buff, 256);
           }


       close(simpleChildSocket);
    }

    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;

}
```

In server part, i want to count data received.

Comment: It depends on the protocol you are using on top of TCP. Are you supposed to define it or is it already specified? (TCP isn't a message protocol but you can build a message protocol on top of it. You can't send a "single message" without a message protocol.)

Comment: What difference does it make where the data comes from? That's basic C. So where is your code? What is your **specific** problem?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: There is no protocol onm top as it reads. Just a string.

Comment: What about a "char buffer server" (whatever that is) makes the problem different in that context?

Comment: @Olaf Then it's impossible. Without a message protocol, there's no such thing as sending a single message. TCP is not a message protocol and you can't send a message without one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Fair enough. I just assumed he transfers simple C strings including `NUL` delimiter. But yes, that **is** some kind of protocol already. I doubt OP has thought about that, though. But even with that it does not make a difference, as he does not ask how to receive, but how to count from a buffer, so we can assume th data has been received already. Which was my point it makes no difference where the data originates from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not know if I got it!

If I understood, are you sending the size of data and the data separeted by space character?

example: "3 123"
3 = length and 123 = data

```
     //server side
     int received;
     /*while(read(simpleChildSocket, buff, 256))*/ 
   
     do{
         received = read(simpleChildSocket, buff, 256);
         if ( received > 0 ) 
             printf("Data received: %s\n", buff);
         else if ( received == 0 )
         {
             printf("Connection closed\n");
             break;
         }
         else
         {
             printf("recv failed -1\n");
             break;
         }
         /*int receved=strlen(buff);*/
         char bufftmp[256]={0};
         /*Loop through the buffer until you find space*/
         for(int k=0;k<received;k++)
         { 
             bufftmp[k]=buff[k];
             if(buff[k]==' ')/*is equal space?*/
             {
                 bufftmp[k]='\0';//make space null
                 int numpart=atoi(bufftmp);
                 printf("lenght of message is: %d\n",numpart);/*get only length*/
                 break;
             } 
         } 
         bzero(buff, 256);

     }while(received>0)
```

Comment: Why call `strlen` when `read` returns the number of bytes returned? And what if `read` returns -1?

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(read(simpleChildSocket, buff, 256)) {
```

The number of bytes that was read from the stream was returned by the `read` function. You should store it somewhere so you can access it later.

Generally, you have two choices for how to tell how many bytes are in a buffer:

1) Just store the number of bytes in a separate integer.

2) If your data is a text string, terminate the text string with a zero byte and then you call `strlen` any time you need to know its length.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't need to know how many bytes are received but if client sends in a single message "1 2 3", server has to count these data and send to client "3" which is the number read of data.

Comment: @Pipox You asked how to count the data received. That's how. If your real question is how to make a message protocol, start by punching "message protocol" into your favorite search engine. But it seems like you're trying to make bricks without straw -- to send and receive messages, you need to use a message protocol. TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol.